# whats the correct way to loop this

Tags: bash, loops, inotify

I have a script where inotifywait is piped into a while loop that executes the following logic.

```
     cp "$S3"/2/post2.png "$S3";
     mv "$S3"/1/post1.png "$S3"/2/post2.png;
     cp "$S3"/3/post3.png "$S3";
     mv "S3"/post2.png "$S3"/3/post3.png;
```

so forth and so on..... then at the end of the script...

```
     mv "$dir"/$file "$S3"/1/post1.png
```

That line represents a fresh post, the above is the rotation of older post.

I can can hand code the iterations all the way down to 100+, but I would like to program more efficiently and save time.

So, what's some correct ways to loop this?

Comment: I don't think that fourth line is right... `mv "$S3"/2/post2.png "$S3"/3/post3.png` maybe?

Comment: What happens to the oldest post? is it disappears or the new directory `$3/nnn` is created for it?

Comment: Are you just trying to shift all the post numbers by one?  How about going in reverse?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean to do.  The shell variable `S3` appears to be irrelevant and you can simplify the question by removing it or specifying some short directory name in its place.  Also state the purposes of the /1/, /2/, /3/ directories.  Say what it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better mechanism would list the directories in `"$S3"` in reverse numeric order, and arrange to process them like that.  It isn't clear if the 100 directories are all present or whether they need to be created.  We'll assume that directories 1..100 might exist, and directory *N* will always and only contain *postN.png*.

I'm assuming that there are no spaces, newlines or other awkward characters in the file paths; this means that `ls` can be used without too much risk.

```
for dirnum in $(cd "$S3"; ls */*.png | sed 's%/.*%%' | sort -nr)
do
    next=$(($dirnum + 1))
    mv "$S3/$dirnum/post$dirnum.png" "$S3/$next/post$next.png"
done
```

The `cd "$S3"` means I don't get a possibly long pathname included in the output; the `ls */*.png` lists the files that exist; the sed removes the file name and slash, leaving just a list of directory numbers containing files; and the sort puts the directories in reverse numeric order.

The rest is straight-forward, given the assumption that the necessary directories already exist.  It would not be hard to add `[ -d "$S3/$next" ] || mkdir -p "$S3/$next"` before moving the file.  Clearly, after the loop you can use your final command:

```
mv "$dir/$file" "$S3/1/post1.png"
```

Note that I've enclosed complete names in double quotes; it generally leads to fewer nasty surprises if something acquires spaces unexpectedly.

Comment: so sick man! you understood the problem perfectly, with limited words just code! im amazed by your code. you jus open up my mind...not only on loops but piping all those commands just to create a variable. FLAWLESS!! thank you mr.leffler!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in $(ls -r1 "$3"); do 
    mkdir -p "$3/$((i+1))"
    mv "$3/$i/post$i.png" "$3/$((i+1))/post$((i+1)).png"
done
mv "$dir"/$file "$S3"/1/post1.png
```

The loop will iterate through all directories in reverse order and move the files.